# How to get from $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to $n + \binom{n}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How to get from $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to $n + \binom{n}{2}$?

I tried some transforming, but my main problem is that I don't know how to get to $n!$ and $(n-2)!$ from the original term.

Comment: Doesn't putting $^nC_2$ as $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ serve your purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a more than casual encounter with the expression $\frac{n(n+1)}2$, then it is useful to know that it is equal to $\binom{n+1}2$, and often better written as such. Here this leads to observing that your equation is just a particular instance of Pascal's recursion (the additive recursion that let's you construct Pascal's triangle without any multiplications):
$$
  \frac{n(n+1)}2 = \binom{n+1}2 = \binom n1+\binom n2 = n +\binom n2
$$
since of course $\binom n1=n$ for all$~n$.

Answer (score 6):

We know that $$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}.$$ By this we have 
$$n+\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}=\binom{n+1}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Just for kicks and giggles (probably not of help to the OP), here is a combinatorial proof.

Let $A$ be a set and $*\not\in A$. Let $\binom{A}{2}$ denote the set of $2$-subsets of $A$. Define a map

$$A\times(A\sqcup\{*\})\to A\sqcup\binom{A}{2}$$

given by $(x,y)\mapsto\{x,y\}$ when $x\ne y$, and $(x,x)\mapsto x$ and $(x,*)\mapsto x$. One may verify that this mapping is $2$-to-$1$, hence taking cardinalities yields $n(n+1)/2=n+\binom{n}{2}$, where $n=|A|$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** 
$$\binom n2 = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} = \frac{n(n-1)}2 $$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a combinatorial proof:

Suppose we have `n` boys and `1` girl in a room and we have to select `2` people out of them.

Then we can do that in $\binom{n+1}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ways since we have `n+1` people to choose from.

Counting in another way. Case 1: There is a girl in our selection. Then we can do that `n` ways. Case 2: There is no girl in our selection. We can do that in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways since we have `n` boys to choose from.

Since these two must be equal. We have:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n+\binom{n}{2}$$